# HTTP window authentication with LDAP using Zend

Tags: http, zend-framework, authentication, ldap

I need to implement LDAP authentication using zend. But for getting user credential, I need to user HTTP authentication method.

I have tried to User HTTP adapter provided by Zend, but in that, I am directly able to authenticate against file created with username:password.
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.auth.adapter.http.html

But I want to get entered username and password (in HTTP window popup) by user and validate it against LDAP using Zend.

Can anyone help me to get required credential in variable ?

Thanks!